# How can I get hierachial pages displaying in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-taxonomy, panels

I would like the content of our site to be structured like this:

site.com/fruits/
site.com/fruits/apples
site.com/fruits/apples/red
site.com/fruits/apples/green

I understand using Taxonomy to setup the Vocabulary and the Terms and categorising the content into this structure.

I would like to use Panels as I am familiar with using it to customise page layout. Ive looked at creating a View, with Taxonomy term as an argument, which seems to work for a single term, but I can seem to get it working on the hierachial path as above ie fruits/apples/red

Ive create a content pane in the View and have created the context in Panels but just cant get it working

Is this something I can achieve with Taxonomy/Pathauto alone  with Panels or how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a detailed guide on doing this, but it doesn't use panels.  You can probably implement it for panels.  You should just follow the guide, first, though.  Then try to apply it:

http://richardsonnen.com/articles/2008/04/creating_hierarchical_web_sites_drupal_6